# How to put together a fix apect ratio div and a div with fix width?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need two `div`. A `left` and a `right` one. Left has a fix aspect ratio (i.e. 2/3), the right one's height is the same as the left one but the width has a fix value i.e. 200px. How can I compose it? Goal is to use as much space of the browser as possible.

[image]

The left fix aspect ratio div is ok:

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.r-4by3-wrap {
  max-width: calc(100vmin * 2 / 3);
  margin: auto;
}

.r-4by3 {
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 150%;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="r-4by3-wrap">
  <div style="border: 10px solid red">
    <div class="r-4by3" style="background: pink">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

but how can put the right one next to the left?

Comment: don't repeat the same question, there is less than 1h between both. Edit the old one to add more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a big fan of lots of nested elements, but you can solve this by wrapping the left and right divs in a parent flex container. Make sure you do the width calculation on the parent and add the 200px you want for the right div:

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: calc(calc(100vmin * 2 / 3) + 200px);
}

.r-4by3-wrap {
  width: calc(100vmin * 2 / 3);
  margin: auto;
}

.r-4by3 {
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 150%;
}

.right {
  border: 10px solid blue;
  background: lightblue;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="r-4by3-wrap">
    <div style="border: 10px solid red">
      <div class="r-4by3" style="background: pink">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi! Do you think it is possible to position `parent` in the center?

Comment: Yes, you can do that by setting it’s left and right margins to `auto`. I updated the answer.

Comment: Hi! Thanks! And I have a bar above the whole parent div. Do you think it is possible to set `padding-top: 150%;` a bit smaller with `44px`? If so, what is the expression for it?

Comment: `padding-top:150%` is what makes it keep the aspect ratio. Of course you can change this based on your preferences. I suggest you experiment with different values to find what fits your site :o)

Answer (score 0):

CSS-Grid can help here:

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.inner {
  border: 10px solid red;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.r-4by3-wrap {
  //max-width: calc(100vmin * 2 / 3);
  margin: auto;
}

.r-4by3 {
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 150%;
  grid-column: 2;
}

.right {
  max-width: 100px;
  /* for demo only */
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="r-4by3-wrap">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="r-4by3" style="background: pink">
    </div>
    <div class="right">Right</div>
  </div>
</div>
```